# style applied using class not working but style attribute works

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS style :

```
.iconBorder{
    border : 3px solid #0aaaa0;
    border-style: dotted;
}
```

I apply the above style to img tag as follows :

```
<img class="iconBorder" src="images/svg/address.svg" height="50px">
```

But the style doesn't seem to render in the browser, it works if I give it as inline CSS:

```
<img class="iconBorder" style="border : 3px solid #0aaaa0;border-style: dotted;" src="images/svg/address.svg" height="50px">
```

What am I missing?, help me figuring it out, thanks in advance.

Comment: you have a typo in the color: `#0aaaa0`

Comment: You can get rid of the second statement and just have border : 3px dotted #0aaaa0; Your code above works for me https://jsfiddle.net/kdrysdale/rn1dxj3m/1/

Comment: Did you call the css file in the head of the html page?    <head><link rel="stylesheet" href="fileName.css"></head> Share complete codes to correct the existing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"  href="mysitestyle.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .iconBorder {
          border: 3px solid #0aaaa0;
          border-style: dotted;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="iconBorder" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" height="50px">
    <img class="iconBorder" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" height="50px">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add your CSS where it should be, this is:

#### Inside a style tag:

```
<style type="text/css">
.iconBorder {
  border: 3px solid #0aaaa0;
  border-style: dotted;
}
</style>
```

#### Included on a .css file referenced the head of your html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"  href="mysitestyle.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
</head>
```

#### Or inline as you already did.

Your code should be totally working and you are having no issues at all.

Example of working CSS from your code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/16u32wfL/).